# jquery.ajax creates non-object error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

hey there i have this jquery:

```
var input = JSON.stringify(data); // output: [100.100]
var lines = input.split('.');
var vari1 = lines[0];  // output: [100
var vari2 = lines[1];  // output: 100]

var data = {'x':vari1+"."+vari2};  
$.ajax({
    url: "checkAvailability.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : {data:JSON.stringify(data)},
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

checkAvailability.php:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($data,true);

if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($data['x'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "is ok", "result"=>1));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "not ok", "result"=>0));
}
```

but than i get:

```
Call to a member function check_availability() on a non-object
```

for this line:

```
if($availabilityChecker->check_availability($data['x'])) {
```

i just want to get this string "100.100" in my check_availability-function, how to do this? greetings

Comment: Well, the error is clear. You didn't create the `$availbilityChecker` object. Where do you initialize it?

Answer (score 3):

in your PHP, it sounds like `$availabilityChecker` is a simple variable or an array. You're trying to call a method inside that object but it's not one to call. To be an object instance it needs to have something like

```
$availabilityChecker = new Class();
```